# Difference between Advanced Power Management and spindown time settings in openmediavault?

Tags: power-management

openmediavault has this dialog for each disk:

[image]

I understand that the APM setting is disk dependent and <= 127 allows spin down while > 127 does not. But if this is the case, what is the difference between that and the spin down time setting below?